# Create new project in visual studio without creating project directory on the disk

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

Is it possible to create a new project in VS 2005 without creating catalogue structure on the disk?
I just want to run a simple snippet from the web and test it, I don't need any new directories or files on my disk.

I remember there was an option for that, but can not find it.

**Solution**: In VS options select "Project and Solutions" and uncheck "Save new projects when created"

Comment: Your solution doesn't actually prevent a project and solution from getting created.  It just happens in a folder that you don't know about.

Comment: Sure you want to know?  %appdata%\local\temporary projects.

Answer (score 1):

No. The project is required for `msbuild` (the compiler) to compile your solution. The compiler needs these files. The `.sln` solution file is required by visual studio to know of the project (`.csproj`).

However you can thin the structure down by building to the same path as the project file (by changing the output folders). You an also skip the solution folder by unchecking 'Create folder for solution' when creating a new solution.

You can even remove the solution file and use the compiler command line tool to build only the project, but you said that you use the IDE.